# Do not copy domain with the feature dataset

Tags: domains

Is there a way to copy a feature dataset to another database with all the features but not carry the domain with it?  Version 10.4.1.  The problem is that I only maintain the domains in the Parent database.  If a domain is edited and then different then the child database, then Arc creates new domain in the child with an _1.  I do not want to have to maintain the domains in all the child databases.

I hope there is a work around this problem

Comment: [Delete Domain](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/delete-domain.htm) tool after the copy